# HTML Theft Prevention

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on designing a website, and I want to make sure that no one can steal the code. I would like to prevent the code from being taken out of the website, and display an error message if a user tries to do so.

Comment: No, you can't, because of the Developer Tools/Inspector. However, you can make a PHP script that will only put some parts of the code on the page, and leave some out.

Comment: Are you living in the Star Trek universe, where downloading code always erases it from the server?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Search for "HTML Obfuscation" - That might help you in finding your answer :)

Comment: @RobertColumbia - that sarcastic comment helps *how*?

Answer (score 4):

HTML Obfuscation is a transformational tool that both preserves the code and prevents it from being reverse-engineered. You can find out more about it [here](https://www.wmtips.com/tools/html-obfuscator/).

Here is an example of obfuscated code.

This is extremely simple HTML code:

```
<a href="mailto:someone@domain.com">Mail me</a>
```

This can be turned into this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var s="=b!isfg>#nbjmup;tpnfpofAepnbjo/dpn#?Nbjm!nf=0b?";
m=""; for (i=0; i<s.length; i++).m+=String.fromCharCode(s.charCodeAt(i)-1); document.write(m);
//-->
</script>
<noscript>
&#13&#10&#60&#97&#32&#104&#114&#101&#102&#61&#34&#109&#97&#105&#108&#116&#111&#58&#115&#111&#109&#101&#111&#110&#101&#64&#100&#111&#109&#97&#105&#110&#46&#99&#111&#109&#34&#62&#77&#97&#105&#108&#32&#109&#101&#60&#47&#97&#62
</noscript>
```

This is called `Combined` obfuscation.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var s="=b!isfg>#nbjmup;tpnfpofAepnbjo/dpn#?Nbjm!nf=0b?";
m=""; for (i=0; i<s.length; i++) m+=String.fromCharCode(s.charCodeAt(i)-1); document.write(m);
//-->
</script>
<noscript>
You must enable JavaScript to see this text.
</noscript>
```

This is called `JavaScript` obfuscation.

```
&#13&#10&#60&#97&#32&#104&#114&#101&#102&#61&#34&#109&#97&#105&#108&#116&#111&#58&#115&#111&#109&#101&#111&#110&#101&#64&#100&#111&#109&#97&#105&#110&#46&#99&#111&#109&#34&#62&#77&#97&#105&#108&#32&#109&#101&#60&#47&#97&#62&#13&#10
```

This is called `Character Entities` obfuscation.

All of these methods are entirely free on that website, and let you keep all your code private.

EDIT:

After further research, I found another website, [JSF**K](http://www.jsfuck.com), which lets you encode items using a series of brackets, parentheses, exclamations and plus signs. Below is how it encodes a simple item:

```
alert(1)
```

becomes:

```
[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]])()
```

This is practically impossible to crack, as you'd need to "fuzz" the website with data to obtain the character codes and then use regular expressions to build a decoder.

Answer (score 2):

@JBDouble05 gave a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52067135/1253479) to your question and I totally recommend it. I wanted to share an example that I threw together for fun, that employs some of the techniques he described. It uses HTML obfuscation via zero-width whitespace characters. I also threw in JSF*CK to *really* make the source code interesting :D

First, the URL which is serving the obfuscated code: http://jackpattishall.com/obfuscated.html

(Uses [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart#Browser_compatibility), so you'll need to view in a browser that supports that!)

If you view the source (using Chrome), you'll notice that 98% or so of the markup *visible* is JSF*CK (basically all those`()` and `[]`):

[image: eval all the way down]

If you scroll long enough, you'll see a `variable` that seems to be assigned nothing:

[image: what is this sorcery!?]

The var `m` is actually assigned the following `zero-width` whitespace characters:

```
const m = "​​‍‍‍‍​​​‍‍​​‍​​​‍‍​‍​​‍​‍‍‍​‍‍​​​‍​​​​​​‍‍​​​‍‍​‍‍​‍‍​​​‍‍​​​​‍​‍‍‍​​‍‍​‍‍‍​​‍‍​​‍‍‍‍​‍​​‍​​​‍​​‍‍​‍‍‍‍​‍‍​​​‍​​‍‍​​‍‍​​‍‍‍​‍​‍​‍‍‍​​‍‍​‍‍​​​‍‍​‍‍​​​​‍​‍‍‍​‍​​​‍‍​​‍​‍​‍‍​​‍​​​​‍​​​‍​​​‍‍‍‍‍​​‍​​‍​​​​‍‍​​‍​‍​‍‍​‍‍​​​‍‍​‍‍​​​‍‍​‍‍‍‍​​‍​‍‍‍​​​‍​​​​​​‍​‍​‍​​​‍‍​‍​​​​‍‍​‍​​‍​‍‍‍​​‍‍​​‍​​​​​​‍‍‍​‍​​​‍‍​​‍​‍​‍‍‍‍​​​​‍‍‍​‍​​​​‍​​​​​​‍‍‍​‍‍‍​‍‍​​​​‍​‍‍‍​​‍‍​​‍​​​​​​‍‍​‍‍‍‍​‍‍​​​‍​​‍‍​​‍‍​​‍‍‍​‍​‍​‍‍‍​​‍‍​‍‍​​​‍‍​‍‍​​​​‍​‍‍‍​‍​​​‍‍​​‍​‍​‍‍​​‍​​​​‍​‍‍‍​​​‍​​​​​​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍‍‍​​‍‍​‍‍​‍​​‍​‍‍​‍‍‍​​‍‍​​‍‍‍​​‍​​​​​​‍​​‍​‍​​‍‍​​​​‍​‍‍‍​‍‍​​‍‍​​​​‍​‍​‍​​‍‍​‍‍​​​‍‍​‍‍‍​​‍​​‍‍​‍​​‍​‍‍‍​​​​​‍‍‍​‍​​​​‍​‍‍​​​​‍​​​​​​‍‍‍​‍‍‍​‍‍​​‍​‍​​‍​​​​​​‍‍‍​‍​​​‍‍‍​​‍​​‍‍​​​​‍​‍‍​‍‍‍​​‍‍‍​​‍‍​‍‍​​‍‍​​‍‍​‍‍‍‍​‍‍‍​​‍​​‍‍​‍‍​‍​​‍​​​​​​‍‍‍​‍​​​‍‍​‍‍‍‍​​‍​​​​​​‍‍‍​​‍‍​‍‍​‍‍‍‍​‍‍​‍‍​‍​‍‍​​‍​‍​‍‍‍​‍​​​‍‍​‍​​​​‍‍​‍​​‍​‍‍​‍‍‍​​‍‍​​‍‍‍​​‍​​​​​​‍‍‍​​‍​​‍‍​​‍​‍​‍‍​​​​‍​‍‍​​‍​​​‍‍​​​​‍​‍‍​​​‍​​‍‍​‍‍​​​‍‍​​‍​‍​​‍​​​​‍​​‍‍‍‍​​​​‍​‍‍‍‍​‍‍​​‍​​​‍‍​‍​​‍​‍‍‍​‍‍​​​‍‍‍‍‍​";
```

Try copy/pasting the previous line in Chrome console. You should get something like:

[image: the man behind the curtain!]

(Any text editor that shows special characters will do the same!)

The `massive` JSF*CK code is basically the following (but minified):

```
const zero_regex = new RegExp(zero, 'g');
const one_regex = new RegExp(one, 'g');

const binToText = text => {
    let str = text.replace(zero_regex, '0').replace(one_regex, '1');
    if (str.match(/[10]{8}/g)) {
        return str.match(/([10]{8}|\s+)/g).map(val => {
            return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(val, 2));
        }).join('');
    }
}
```

The `script` responsible for the obfuscation looks like:

```
// Our zero-width whitespace chars
const zero = '​';
const one = '‍';

const textToBin = text => {
    let len = text.length;
    let output = [];
    let i = 0;
    for (; i < len; i++) {
        output.push(text[i].charCodeAt().toString(2).padStart(8, '0'));
    }
    return output.join('').replace(/0/g, zero).replace(/1/g, one);
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle that shows a bit more of the `magic`:

http://jsfiddle.net/z5gu4bq1/

Hope this was helpful. Have fun with JavaScript! And please never do this in Production :)

Resources:

1. [JSF*CK](http://www.jsfuck.com/)
2. [White-space Obfuscation Reference](https://github.com/beardog108/snow10)